# Is running our workstation network through VoIP handset best practice?

Tags: networking, cisco, voip

We are purchasing a Cisco UC VoIP phone system and the handsets come in two flavors: 100mb and 1gb. Both allow network pass-through of another device such as a printer or workstation. Is this an acceptable solution that won't cause loss of desktop icons or slow bandwidth if a call comes in? I understand that everything will be separated by VLANs and all of our switches are PoE.

Comment: `Is this an acceptable solution that won't cause loss of desktop icons`  <-- Uh... I think you're in over your head.  You need to hire or consult with someone who knows something about networking.

Comment: Loss of desktop icons? Could you please edit your question and explain why you think this might be an issue?

Comment: To add a bit of dimension to the above skepticism, it's extremely common for shops with Cisco VoIP phones to run their workstation network connection through the phone. We do. We had problems with some ancient 100MbE NICs, but not since then.

Comment: All of our users desktop & documents are re-directed to a server share. We just wanted to make sure someone with experience running workstations through VoIP handsets had no bandwidth issues.

Comment: We run two lines...depending on the amount of traffic, we didn't want to run into the potential of overwhelming the switches.

Comment: How would you overwhelm the switch? A shared 1Gb media can only transmit at 1Gb no matter how many devices are on the other side.

Comment: @MDMarra Dunno, honestly. Plus, we only have 100mb phones here. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know whether or not it's an official "best practice" or not, but it's certainly common.  I've never heard of it causing an issue at any of my workplaces.  We were not using roaming profiles, but we were using network-intensive applications and performing software installs via the network, and, again, we never had any report of slowness due to a call coming in.

Comment: Thanks so much! And thanks for not being snarky. ;-)